# Disable HTML5 form validation for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

In an HTML page, there have 5 different forms. Four of them are in the bootstrap modal. HTML5 validation pops up for all forms on the main form submit. How can we disable the HTML5 validation for the forms other than submitting the form?

Comment: Do share your markup...

Comment: Just add **novalidate** attribute to your form

Comment: @HoangDo — I think OP is expected his primary form to be validated!

Comment: @HoangDo -But will the validation work for the modal form when bootstrap modal pops up?

Comment: @Rayon ya I dont clearly understand his question xD

Comment: @user2190981 if you do so, there will no validation at all. You better add a code snippet, so every body can help you easier

Comment: Voting to close as a typo per OP's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 validation popup for the forms other than the main form was appearing on submitting the main form because one of the forms was not closed properly. So the scope of the form affected the problem and treated as a single form and so the HTML5 validation.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `novalidate` attribute to the form tag:

```
<form name="something" novalidate></form>
```

Ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-novalidate

Comment: but it will affect the modal popup validation permanently, right?

Comment: It will affect only that specific form in which "novalidate" is added.